# render method in rails outputs wrong script tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

so I have this piece of line in my haml file in views

%script {:charset => "utf-8", :src => "http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"}

but when I load it and check the javascript console in chrome, it is outputting this instead.

{:charset => "utf-8", :src => "http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"}

What could be hte problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space after `%script`. Remove that, and it'll work fine:

`%script{:charset => "utf-8", :src => "http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"}`